# Convergent vs Divergent Sequence Definition

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

1. What is the actual definition of divergent sequence?
2. Is Not convergent implies Divergent?
3. Is oscillatory sequence divergent or another type different from convergent and divergent sequences.

my last question is a(n) = (-1)^n is divergent / oscillatory / both?

Comment: A sequence is said to be divergent if it is not convergent.

Comment: The notion of a sequence being convergent or divergent can be defined in a broader context than real analysis, e.g. in the setting of topological spaces.  If you are only interested in sequences of real numbers (as the tag suggests), it would be good practice to state that in the body of your Question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.